# Problem referencing a .NET5 project in a source generator library

Tags: c#, .net

I have a source generator library and I need to reference a .NET5 library to it. Problem is that source generators apparently **have** to be contained in .NETstandard 2.0 libraries for some reason, and it isn't possible to reference .NET5 projects inside .NETstandard projects.
The .NET5 project is a library that contains some Models for a Blazor application, it contains some code like tag attributes for validation forms that simply won't work if I converted the project to .NETstandard.
Any possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this.

**Multi-target the .NET 5 project (notice: it's TargetFramework*s*)**

```
 <TargetFrameworks>net5.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

**Use preprocessor directives to avoid any errors in the portions of code that require .NET 5**

```
#if NET5_0
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You have to insert a valid price")]
#endif
```

You can probably proceed in this way in any given scenario where you have to reference a .NET 5 or .NET Core project inside of a .NET standard project.